# How can I get cognito user pool client ID in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using `terraform` to manage IaC in AWS in my project. `cognito` is already existing on AWS and it has a user pool and its related resources. How can I reference the client ID in my terraform? I have tried below setting:

```
data "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "selected" {
  name = "app-client"
}
```

I got this error:

```
The provider provider.aws does not support data source
"aws_cognito_user_pool_client".
```

It seems AWS doesn't support data source for `aws_cognito_user_pool_client`. Is there another way to get the client ID?

Answer (score 2):

User pool client is a resource, not a data source so it should look like this:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "test" {
  name         = "app-client"
}
```

Of course, if it already exists within Cognito yo will have to import it.

```
terraform import aws_cognito_user_pool_client.test id-of-client-in-cognito
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no data source for a aws_cognito_user_pool_client

There is a data source for aws_cognito_user_pools

The correct syntax for the aws_cognito_user_pools data source is -

```
data "aws_cognito_user_pools" "selected" {
  name = "app-pool"
}
```

Source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cognito_user_pools